# access scope from ag-grid cell template

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to trigger a angular js function (ng-blur) from ag-grid cell template?

Below is my column definition for ag-grid

```
var columnDefs = [
          {headerName: "Make", field: "make" , template:'<input type="text" class="form-control control-width-90 margin-left-5" ng-blur="alert(\'wewew\')"/>'},
          {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
          {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
        ];
```

Data for ag-grid

```
var rowData = [
          {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
          {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
          {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
        ];
```

Grid Options

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
              columnDefs: columnDefs,
              rowData: rowData
};
```

Output
[PFA for the output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEttX.png

Based on the column definition I am able to render the template but unable to trigger the event on blur.
Can anyone suggest me how to trigger the event from custom template or access scope from ag-grid custom template?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to trigger event on cell value change ?
Then you can use (cellValueChanged) event of ag grid.

Comment: cellValueChanged event is trigger with ag-grid default column definition.In my case i have a custom cell template for column definition and trigger an event on blur of my input element. You can have look on my column definition where i have mentioned a template for the field 'make'.

Comment: in that case user cellRenderer instead of template as below : 
      cellRenderer:  (params) => { 
          let input = document.createElement("INPUT");
          input.setAttribute("type", "text");
          input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
            this.onblur();
          });
          return input;
      }